# How to insert extra lines of white space in LyX?

Tags: spacing, lyx

I often use LyX as my word processor, including just for typing notes for myself.

Is it possible to add extra lines of white space in the **LyX display**? (So, this is not the same as the question ["How to Add Whitespace to Lyx?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225258/how-to-add-whitespace-to-lyx).)

As illustrated in the below GIF, I keep trying to hit `Enter` and there's temporarily the desired extra line of white space, but once I go elsewhere, that line disappears:

[image]

---

A very crude solution I'm now using is to insert a graphic (highlighted below) that has the same color as the LyX background color:

[image]

But obviously this isn't a very desirable solution as I have to copy-paste this graphic every time I want an additional blank line of space. (Not to mention that I have that rather inelegant and useless graphic there for almost no reason.)

Are there maybe smarter and more efficient solutions?

Comment: A smart solution would IMHO be to just paragraph skip instead of indent and therefore the question you've already linked would be suitable. Why do you thing, that it isn't? But maybe the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135134/277964 would be, what you want.

Comment: I found the answer I wanted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152001/309043